# Should I select a feature used to define the target for my model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am doing feature selection for a regression model. The target is defined as the ratio of two input features, let's say `target = feature1/feature2`.

To perform feature selection I am computing Pearson Correlation

1. Between all my features and the target, selecting the features with correlation > 0.1
2. Of these features I will further select those that are uncorrelated with each other.

My doubt is: as a result of this process, feature1 and feature2 (which I used to define the target) have been selected in the first step as they are correlated to the target.

Should I consider feature1 and feature2 as predictors for my model? Or should I drop them to prevent overfitting?

I haven't found anything discussing this specific case. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how you plan to use the model? For prediction, the first order concern would be [data leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)) rather than overfitting. This would not be an issue for say dimension reduction.

Comment: Yes it is for prediction of the target.

Comment: If you knew an exact formula for your target in terms of your available features, then overfitting would be a non-issue. In your training data, are the target values given independently of the features?

Comment: My target is exactly the fraction of two features target=feature1/feature2 as said in the post. What do you mean: are the target values given independently of the features? and also what does mean: overfitting would be a non-issue

Comment: @GeoMatt22 the target is computed and created.